# How can I learn Undergraduate Mathematics by self-study as my college lectures are not clear enough?

Tags: calculus, self-learning, problem-solving, mathematical-physics, education

I am an Electrical Engineering undergraduate student. I have just joined college, so I am currently a freshman. I wish to pursue Masters in Mathematics after graduation. In order to be competent enough for Masters course, I need to study Mathematics on my own.

I have read answers related to my question but none of them seem to address my query. My questions are:

1. Should I learn from books or from videos available on Internet (such as MIT OCW)? Also mention the resources which I should follow.
2. As a student, I find many topics like Calculus intriguing and I am curious to dive deep into learning them. On the other hand, I feel unmotivated to learn some topics like Statistics. How should I deal with such topics?
3. Which roadmap should I follow? I tried OSSU Mathematics curicullum but it didn't seem to fit in.
4. How much time should I invest in solving problems? Personally, I like to solve real-world problems. I want to know whether mathematical geniuses are nurtured by intuitive thinking or problem-solving. I also want to know what makes them exceptionally good at math - discipline or curiosity.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. Both are fine approaches. Some people can learn from just reading a text, others need to watch lectures. Either way, most learning happens when you solve problems, like exercises in the back of a textbook. Try to learn the concepts, and attempt the problems.

Comment: @NoChance I actually got here in Engineering by chance. I want to make Maths my main subject and adopt it after graduation. So tell me the answer from Mathematician's point of view.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I know I should not have said that in a Math StackExchange...But for someone who is an Electrical Engineer, I thought there may be an exception, otherwise building the necessary background in Math would be an endless endeavor!

Comment: I retracted my original advice as it was based on the fact that you are studying Electrical Engineering and want to build a background in Math. to help you with EE. My advice now is think before you jump! It is a wild world.

Comment: In my years, libraries were best friends but now there is only internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend books.

It is important to find the right book for you, on any given topic in Math.  A book that is right for someone else may not be right for you.

Generically, you want a book that offers many, many exercises for you to solve.  My experience has been that about $20\%$ of my learning takes place by studying the text of the Math book, and about $80\%$ of my learning occurs when I tackle the exercises.

In effect, the exercises represent applications of the text, that force you to really understand the text.  MathSE can then be a great tool for posting those exercises that you are unable to solve.  You merely have to follow the protocol in [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

As for finding the right texts, my first choice would be to seek out a **working Math professor**, at your school, rather than someone with an Engineering PHD, or (for example) the chairman of the Math department, or (for example) a Math teaching assistant.

You want someone in the business of being directly responsible (to a limited extent) for the student's learning.

A reasonable secondary approach is to review MathSE postings that are tagged *book-recommendation* or *reference-request*.  You can couple this with an examination of the book reviews on a site like Amazon.com.

Then, the final issue is which Math topics to attack, and in what order.  Here, I would (again) go straight to a working Math professor, explain the problem, and let him suggest the Math topics, and the order in which they should be tackled.